# What is the correct approach to solve SPOJ DIEHARD?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, greedy

I was trying to solve a practice question on SPOJ https://www.spoj.pl/problems/DIEHARD/ .
However both my greedy approach resulted in Wrong Answer and recursion was too slow for the worst case.Can anyone tell how to approach this problem? I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

> The game is simple. You initially have ‘H’ amount of health and ‘A’ amount of armor. At any instant you can live in any of the three places - fire, water and air. After every unit time, you have to change your place of living. For example if you are currently living at fire, you can either step into water or air.
>
> - If you step into air, your health increases by 3 and your armor increases by 2
> - If you step into water, your health decreases by 5 and your armor decreases by 10
>     If you step into fire, your health decreases by 20 and your armor increases by 5
>
> If your health or armor becomes <=0, you will die instantly
>
> Find the maximum time you can survive.
>
> Input:
>
> The first line consists of an integer t, the number of test cases. For each test case there will be two positive integers representing the initial health H and initial armor A.
>
> Output:
>
> For each test case find the maximum time you can survive.

Comment: What is the maximal input of H and A?

Comment: "Input Constraints:

1<=t<=10
1<=H,A<=1000
"

Comment: Have you tried the greedy solution? Go to air whenever possible because that increases everything, otherwise if armor > health go to water otherwise if it doesn't kill you go to fire.

Comment: @IVlad:sir,i got wrong answer with the approach you described.Can you prove validity of the greedy approach here

Comment: @user1724072 no, it was just a thought. I don't have a working greedy, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, Firstly try solving it by greedy approach.
It is obvious that air is the best choice possible as it increases both armor and health but you can go to air alternately only. So every odd(i.e 1,3,5...) move will be to air. Now we have to decide what to do with even moves?

So we have two choices Fire or water? We have to be reasonable and choose such a move that keeps both H and A above 0. Now jumping in fire costs health -20 even though it increases armor by 5, but hey wait, what is the use of increased armor if you don't get your health >0 . So if H>5 and A>10 choose water.

Now what if we are short of armor but have enough health? In that case we have no choice but to jump to fire.

So now we have a greedy approach:

So, if we have sufficient H and A, we'll go to water.
Else, if H is sufficient enough and A is not sufficient, go to fire.
Else, it's over!

Here is the ideone link of implementation:
http://ideone.com/rkobNK

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    long long int x,i,a,b,t,h,arm;
    scanf("%lld",&x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        scanf("%lld %lld",&a,&b);
        if(a==0||b==0)
         printf("0\n");
        else{
            t=1;
            h=a+3;
            arm=b+2;
            while(1){
                if(h>5&&arm>10){
                    h=h-2;
                    arm=arm-8;
                    t=t+2;
                }else if(h>20&&arm<=10){
                    h=h-17;
                    arm=arm+7;
                    t=t+2;
                }else {
                    printf("%lld\n",t);
                    break;
                }
            }
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the else if condition you need not to check for arm<=10 because if h>20 is true it means if part went false because arm was <=10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it analytically:

```
a = number of times visiting air state
F = number of times visiting fire state
W = number of times visiting water state

M = a + F + W  // total moves

// positive
a >= 0
F >= 0
W >= 0

// because of the restriction of moving between states...
a <= F + W + 1
F <= W + a + 1
W <= a + F + 1

// the effect of armor and health...
H < -3a + 5H + 20F
A < -2a + 10W - 5F
```

Maximize M.  You can do this by binary searching for M, or you can use linear programming.

Binary search loop:

```
int ok = 0;
int impossible = 1000000000;
while (impossible - ok > 1)
{
    int candidate = ok + (impossible-ok) / 2;

    if (check(candidate))
        ok = candidate;
    else
        impossible = candidate;
}
return ok;
```

In either case use basic high school algebra to simplify the inequalities/equation.

Comment: Can you detail how to binary search `M`? In what interval, and what do you do for a given candidate value `k` in that interval?

Comment: Well 0 is always ok and 10^9 is always impossible, so that's your interval.  For a fixed M you need to decide whether M is ok or impossible.  Manipulate the inequalities using algebra to do this.

Comment: How efficiently can you compute `check`? I can't see a way to do it much better than the brute force.

Comment: You have 6 equations in 3 unknowns (a,F,W).  Recall that M, H and A are now constant.  It is high school algebra.  (constant time)

Comment: You don't have 6 equations, you have one equation and at least 3 inequalities.

Comment: That's what I meant.  Solve the first for a (`a = M + F + W`),  substitute out a, leaving 2 unknowns (F,W) - and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I did by using dynamic progamming.
Dp[health][armour][air/fire/water]- is the maximum time you can live if you start from this condition
then the recurrent conditions simply become
Dp[health][armour][air/fire/water]=1+max of the next states you can go to
Obviousy the base case is when he can go nowhere so the answer for that becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DFS?  The state is a tuple of (air|fire|water, H, A).  This has:

```
3 * 1000 * 1000 = 3,000,000 game states
```

Do a DFS on it and find the highest moves.  (ie set everything to -1 and the initial states to 0, then DFS from 0 states to all reachable positions)

Comment: :What should be the source and destination vertex for this problem ?

Comment: The source is the inital states.  The array keeps track of the highest number of moves to reach that state.

Comment: Actually it is a little more complicated than I have let on but the general approach should work.

Comment: :I have already tried a  lot.Most people have soled this question in 0.00s ,so i think it might be a lot more easier.

Comment: Well there is an analytic solution.  The order you visit the states is not important, so setup a system of linear inequalities and solve them with algebra.  (Or you could binary search on them.)

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling what do you mean the order you visit the states is not important? For example, it's easy to find an example that lets you survive more if you pick air first, because it increases both health and armor.

Comment: @IVlad: No I mean the cost of visiting air, fire and water doesn't change depending on the order in which you visit it.  So it is a sufficient statistic to simply ask how many times you visit each state.  See my other answer.